# How to remove the server error on loading of new form in openerp?

Tags: python, eclipse, odoo

I have been working on creating a custom module in my openerp server v7. As I am using win 7 , I am running the python code on my eclipse IDE . I have creted a button on my module and it will load a new form on click . Now when I click the button , the new form is loading but I am getting " openerp server error " . Also the fields I defined are not there on my new form . I dont know where I am getting wrong . Plz help.

Hopes for suggestion

here is my python code

```
from osv import fields, osv
import time

class my_module(osv.osv):
    _name="my.module"
    _columns={
         'name':fields.char('Name',size=64),
         'proj':fields.char('Proj-Details',size=64)     
            }

    def add_field(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
           return {
         'name':'formview', 
         'view_mode': 'form',
         'view_type': 'form',
         'res_id' : 'form_view_action2', # id of the object to which to redirected
         'res_model': 'ir.actions.act_window', # object name
         'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
         'target': 'new' # if you want to open the form in new tab
        }   




class new_module(osv.osv):
    _name="new.module"
    _columns={
          'date':fields.date('date')    
              }
```

here is my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<openerp>
    <data>


       <record model="ir.ui.view" id="from_view_form">
            <field name="name">from.view.form</field>
            <field name="model">my.module</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Form" version="7.0">
                    <group>
                        <field name="name" />
                        <field name="proj" />
                        <button name="add_field" string="Add Field" type="object"  class="oe_highlight" />
                    </group>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>


        <record model='ir.actions.act_window' id='form_view_action2'>
            <field name="name">Form</field>
            <field name="res_model">new.module</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Click to create a new record.
                </p>
                <p>This is a test class developed to learn Openerp.</p>
            </field>
        </record>


       <record model='ir.actions.act_window' id='form_view_action'>
            <field name="name">Form</field>
            <field name="res_model">my.module</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
            <field name="context">{}</field>
            <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">
                    Click to create a new record.
                </p>
                <p>This is a test class developed to learn Openerp.</p>
            </field>
        </record>





        <menuitem name="newforms" id="newforms_ID" sequence="110" />
        <menuitem name="newforms2" parent="newforms_ID" id="newforms2_ID" sequence="0" />
        <menuitem name="newforms3" parent="newforms2_ID" id="newforms3_ID" action='form_view_action' />
        <menuitem name="newforms4" id="newforms4_ID" action='form_view_action2' />



    </data>
</openerp>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that I have to stop/restart the OpenERP server itself to get changes to the `.py` file to take effect.

Comment: I dont know what u r trying to say

Comment: @ArsalanSherwani: Stop the OpenERP server running on your Windows machine; Start the OpenERP server with the switch `-u my_module`.

Comment: The -u my_module switch means update the module but you need to also tell it the database with -d so if you combine these (-d my_database -u my_module) then each time you restart OpenERP it will update your module in your database.